# Sampling from single channel textures in DirectX

Tags: directx, textures, direct3d, hlsl

I have a 2D texture formatted as DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT. In my pixel shader I sample from it thusly:

```
float sample = texture.Sample(sampler, coordinates);
```

This results in the following compiler warning:

> warning X3206: implicit truncation of vector type

I'm confused by this. Shouldn't [Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) return a single channel, and therefore a scalar value, as opposed to a vector?

I'm using shader model 4 level 9_1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare your texture as having one channel, or specify which channel you want. Without the `<float>` bit, it'll assume it's a 4 channel texture and so therefore Sample will return a float4.

```
Texture2D<float> texture;
```

or

```
float sample = texture.Sample(sampler, coordinates).r;
```

Comment: The texture is declared as R32_FLOAT on the CPU side. On the GPU side, my texture is currently declared in the shader as "Texture2D texture". Is there something else I need to do to specify that it has only one channel?

Comment: Oh, I see what's happened here, StackOverflow's formatting removed two instances of '<float>'.

'Texture2D<float> texture; '

is what you want, I'll edit my answer.